# Madrid city pass

Tags: tickets, spain, madrid

I will be traveling to Madrid next week for three days, and would like to know if there is some sort of city pass [like there is for Barcelona](https://www.barcelonapass.com/):

> The Barcelona Pass is a comprehensive sightseeing package, which allows visitors to experience the best of Barcelona while saving time and money. Available in 2 and 3 consecutive day durations, The Barcelona Pass includes free entry to 15+ attractions, monuments and museums, helping you unlock the best of the city!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [Madridcard](http://www.gomadrid.com/activity/madridcard.html):

> Once purchased, the card offers FREE entrance to more than 50 Madrid museums, sights and tours, rides on the Teleferico cable car, complimentary entrance to the Real Madrid museum tour, discounts in restaurants, shops, shows, and many other items completely free of charge.

There is an [Attraction Pass/iVenture Card](http://madrid.city-tour.com/en/iventure-card) which looks like its from a private company ([more info](https://www.viator.com/tours/Madrid/iVenture-Card-Mard/d566-2140P192))

> The Attraction Pass is a smart card that offers activity packages with which you will be able to save up to 40%. You only have to choose your favorite attractions and incorporate them in your card. We offer you a great range of more than 20 attractions such as Madrid City Tour, tours, museums and entertainment.

There is also a [travel pass](https://www.esmadrid.com/en/madrid-tourist-travel-pass) for public transport

Comment: I went just for the travel pass which worked really well. The "Madrid Card" didn't had too many good reviews so i opted not to buy it.

Thanks for the help.